# Getting PHP session array values into Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have stored array values in PHP session.

Now I want to retreive this array and convert it to javascript aray.

This is how I set PHP session:

```
var listone = ["one", "two", "three"];

function setSession(listone){
    $.get(
        "setSession.php",
        {listone:listone} 
    );
}
```

So if once these values are set and I refresh the page, I check if the session has been set. If set, I want to do something like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['listone']))
{
?>
  listone = Array('<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['listone']) ?>');
<?php
}
?>
```

When I do this, the 'listone' array is showing me like this:

```
listone[0] = [
listone[1] = "
listone[2] = o
listone[3] = n
listone[4] = e
listone[5] = "
.... etc
```

I know I am doing something wrong.
Is it the way I am storing the array in PHP session?
or
Is it the way I am retrieving it back to JS?

Thanks for any pointers. I am willing to dig more if guided properly :)

Comment: you have just to learn to separate PHP from JS. Your second code snippet is one that makes no sense.

Comment: sorry my second code had error. I changed it.

Comment: `listone = Array('<?php echo ` : do you see that you echo in a string? Remove the quotes, remove the `Array()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be trying to do one of two things here- either something to do with AJAX, which is expecting a JS response, or you're trying to access a session variable directly in JS.

If you simply wish to switch a PHP variable into a JS readable array, you can do:

```
json_encode($_SESSION['myarray']);
```

This would need to be a response readable & interpreted elsewhere by a JS script (e.g. an AJAX response).

PHP session variables arent accessable through JS directly, however, you can construct JS within PHP, wrapping the two together so you use PHP to output JS populated with the data held within your PHP session variable. The key here is the order of the code, and how your JS is structured- i.e. you will probably want to reference a global JS variable  so the values are accessible by your other JS- or call a function etc...

So, you could have:

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['myarray'])){
         $_SESSION['myarray']=array('one', 'two', 'three');
}

echo "<script type='text/javascript'>

var myJSvariable = new Array();";

foreach($_SESSION['myarray'] as $key=>$value){
      echo "myJSvariable[".$key."]=".$value.";";
}

echo "</script>";
```

Comment: A little bit of modification to this script made it work for me :)   ....... btw. I appreciate everyone who helped.... some of the suggestions might be useful as I code further...

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your php file to this or a similar one

```
<?php
session_start();
$result = array();

if(isset($_SESSION['listone'])) {
   $result['listone'] = $_SESSION['listone'];
}

echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

[json_encode](http://www.php.net/json_encode) translate your array into a json array and you don't need to create a new one.

Plus I would put the required variables into an hash array and return just the json_encode of that array in order to have a cleaner code.